# Ruby - Can someone explain each line of this code to me

Tags: ruby

I have to make a method that will add commas to numbers. I cannot use regular expressions in the method. After a lot of tinkering and research, I found this solution, that works:

```
def separate_comma(number)
    c = { :value => "", :length => 0 }
    r = number.to_s.reverse.split("").inject(c) do |t, e|
        iv, il = t[:value], t[:length]
        iv += ',' if il % 3 == 0 && il != 0
        { :value => iv + e, :length => il + 1 }
    end
    r[:value].reverse!
end
```

Can someone help me out here and explain the syntax for each line? There's a lot going on here, and I'm having a hard time grasping all of it. Also, any ideas on how to refactor it and make it more elegant-without using regex's. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

```
def separate_comma(number)
c = { :value => "", :length => 0 }
```

c is a hash with :value = "" and length = 0 (it will be used later)

```
r = number.to_s.reverse.split("").
```

the number is converted to a string, reversed and split into digits. Example:

```
19874 --> ["4","7","8","9","1"]
```

---

```
.inject(c) do |t, e|
```

Inject "Combines all elements of enum by applying a binary operation, specified by a block or a symbol that names a method or operator"

It transforms a 'memo' using the current array item, resulting in a new memo that is used for the next array item.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject

In this case each array item will modify the 'c' hash

```
    iv, il = t[:value], t[:length]
```

iv initially equals c:value and il equals c:length

```
    iv += ',' if il % 3 == 0 && il != 0
```

this will add a comma before the current array item if the current count is a multiple of three ( im my example this will only apply to the 4th array item (this will be clear later)

```
    { :value => iv + e, :length => il + 1 }
```

the (possibly modified) array item is appended to the string in our t[:value] hash and the :length is incremented by one

```
end
```

working through my example

**1**

```
iv = ""
il = 0
e = "4"
returns { :value "4", :length 1}
```

**2**

```
iv = "4"
il = 1
e = "7"
returns { :value "47", :length 2}
```

**3**

```
iv = "47"
il = 2
e = "8"
returns { :value "478":, :length 3}
```

**4**

```
iv = "478"
il = 3
e = "9," (the if statement returns true and so a comma is appended to the 9)
returns { :value "478,9", :length 4}
```

**5**

```
iv = "478,9"
il = 4
e = 1
returns { :value "478,91", :length 5}
```

(this is returned by the inject statement)

```
r[:value].reverse!
```

takes the value returned by the inject statement and reverses it's characters.
   "19,874"
end

In terms of making the code easier to understand, you could use these more descriptive variable names:

```
c = number_hash_memo
r = result
t = number_hash
e = char
iv = hash_val
il = hash_length
```

Answer (score 1):

**`c = { :value => "", :length => 0 }`**

c is a hash that contains two key-pairs, the first key is `value` an empty string, the second is `length` which is 0.

The purpose of this line was used to create the initial state of the object entered into the inject method.

**`number.to_s.reverse.split("")`**

Will return an array of 'number' in reversed order, for example:

`number = 12345
 number.to_s.reverse.split("")
 => ["5", "4", "3", "2", "1"]`

**`r = number.to_s.reverse.split("").inject(c) do |t, e|`**

Enumerable#inject is a fancy method in the ruby community. It's taking in a hash and a block. The initial state of the object is the `hash` you input inside the inject method. The 't' in `|t,e|` is an object set by the return value of the last line of code in the inject block and its initial state is the hash entered into the inject method. And 'e' in `|t,e|` is the element in the array you are iterating over.

**`iv, il = t[:value], t[:length]`**

These are values you are setting throughout each iteration.

**`iv += ',' if il % 3 == 0 && il != 0`**

Under the condition that the length is 3 and not 0 add a comma. So after every three iteration a comma is added into your value object.

**`{ :value => iv + e, :length => il + 1 }`**

The return value of the last line in the Enumerable#inject method is passed to the 't' object.

**`r[:value].reverse!`**

The block of code will return 't'.
Then finally the value is reversed back to its original state and returned.

Answer (score 0):

What you posted works, but it's a very inefficient solution. Rather than refactoring it, it's better to just rewrite it:

```
def separate_comma(number)
  digits = number.to_s.reverse.split('')
  buffer = []
  buffer << digits.shift(3).join until digits.empty?
  buffer.join(',').reverse
end
```

This should also be much easier to follow.

Comment: It's nice, but the question asks for an explanation of the given code, not for a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

this would be easier

1. take number  (eg: number => 12345678)
2. convert it to string ("12345678")
3. reverse it ("87654321")
4. convert it to array (["8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"])
5. try to make subarrays with 3 element # the last one will contain remainder ( [["8", "7", "6"], ["5", "4", "3"], ["2", "1"]])
6. iterate over subarray to push comma to the last place of subarrays, except last one
7. join array to make a string
8. reverse the string

[here is the code](http://repl.it/iP0) i've written

```
def comma_seperate(number)
    s = number.to_s.reverse.split(//).each_slice(3).to_a
    i = 0
    while i<s.length-1
        s[i].push(",")
        i+=1
    end
    s.join().reverse
end
```

Comment: I suggest two changes:  6. Use `t = s.map(&:join)` to convert each of the arrays to a string (["876", "543", "21"]), 7. use t.join(',') to convert the array to a string with commas ("876,543,21").

Comment: I just wiped that code out totally, and rewrote it the way that you guys had suggested. It is much more efficient and not nearly as crazy to read. Thank you for the in depth explanation oli5679 and Menelik!