# Adding ", " after 3 chars from back

Tags: python, range, python-2.5

I just tried to show a ", " between each 3 characters!

I tried it with:

```
players = ','.join([player[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(player), 3)])
rankedplayers = ','.join([ranked[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(ranked), 3)])
points = ','.join([totalpoints[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(totalpoints), 3)])
```

But it only starts from left side to right, how I can do it from back so right to left?

Edit:

For example

```
player = 9502
ranked = 2040
totalpoints = 12390
```

And the output would be:

```
player 950,2
ranked 204,0
totalpoints = 123,90
```

It should be:

```
player = 9,502
ranked = 2,040
totalpoints = 12,390
```

Comment: Can you give us some sample input and expected output?

Comment: i proposed a way for it here- http://stackoverflow.com/a/29584257/4481312
you can just adapt it to your code, if you want.

@Eran's answer is better :)

Answer (score 3):

you can reverse the range to go from the other side, like so:

```
player = ','.join([player[i:i+3] for i in reversed(range(0, len(player), 3))])
```

but for grouping numbers with commas, what you really want to do is:

```
player = "{:,}".format(int(player))
```

Answer (score 2):

This `regex` does exactly what you need:

`(/(\d)(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,')`

Best used with a `replace` method.